# Redirect the URL from one query string to another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have spent a great many hours trying to find a solution to this and tried many different approaches but nothing I have tried has worked so far.

I would like to redirect a URL with a query string to another URL that contains the value of that query string.

I want to redirect:

`https://example.com/component/search/?searchword=XXXXXXXXX&searchwordsugg=&option=com_search`

to

`https://example.com/advanced-search?search=XXXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following using mod_rewrite at the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)searchword=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^component/search/?$ /advanced-search?search=%1 [NE,R=302,L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. To match against the query string we need a separate *condition* that checks against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

`%1` is a backreference to the first *capturing* group in the preceding *CondPattern*, ie. the *value* of the `searchworld` URL parameter.

The regex `(?:^|&)searchword=([^&]*)` matches the `searchworld` URL parameter *anywhere* in the query string, not just at the start (as in your example). This also permits an *empty* value for the URL parameter.

The `NE` *flag* is required to prevent the captured URL parameter value being doubly encoded in the response. (Since the `QUERY_STRING` server variable is not %-decoded.)

The `L` flag prevents further processing during this pass of the rewrite engine.

Reference:

- [Apache docs: `RewriteRule` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
- [Apache docs: `RewriteCond` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)